# How do I make a symmetrical downward pointing angle that is greater than 90 degrees using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I've tried using various iterations of skew to get outline of an angle like this with pure CSS:

[image: downward facing angle]

It never seems to come out right. I can easily make a 90 degree angle with rotation and a border, but getting a greater than 90 degree angle has escaped me. I'm actually using less, but this more of a css question.

Solid shapes I understand how do to, it is achieving the border with a transparent background that I can't figure out.

Comment: Perhaps you could share your HTML/CSS. With that reputation I would have expected a JSFiddle.

Comment: I don't have anything that works. It's basically a box with a border. I add a .rotate using bootstraps's less mixin to get a downward facing angle, but it's 90 degrees.

Comment: Did you search for CSS shapes? Here in an example that have been a bit altered: http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/QefLR/1/

Comment: These are solid shapes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as well with pseudo elements: http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/LGtap/

from `<div>Envellope</div>` :

```
div {
  width:500px;
  height:194px;
  background:#2F374B;
  position:relative;/* to master pseudo position */
  text-align:center;
}
div:before,
div:after {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  width:57%;/* update this to match with rotation degrees */

  box-shadow:0 0 3px 2px #363E55;
  top:2px; /* size of shadow */
  left:2px;/* size of shadow */
 transform:rotate(30deg);
   transform-origin:top left;
}
div:after {
  transform:rotate(-30deg);
     transform-origin:top right;
  left:auto;
  right:2px;/* size of shadow */
}
```

Playing with multiple box-shadow, you can increase the look a of a letter [image: box-shadow letter]

```
div:before,
div:after {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  width:57.5%;
  height:1px;
  background:#456;
  box-shadow:0 0 3px 2px #363E55,
    340px -82px  4px 1px  #363E55,
    0 3px  5px black;
  ;

  top:2px;
  left:2px;
  transform:rotate(30deg);
  transform-origin:top left;
}
div:after {
  transform:rotate(-30deg);
  transform-origin:top right;
  left:auto;
  right:2px;
  background:#456;
  box-shadow:0 0 3px 2px #363E55,
    -340px -82px  4px 1px  #363E55,
    0 3px  5px black;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yvCuo/)

One base element & pseudo elememt

**CSS**

```
.box {
  width:600px;
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid grey;
  margin:25px auto;
  position: relative;
}

.box:after {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  width:0;
  height:0;
  border:300px solid transparent;
  border-width:150px 300px;
  border-top-color: lightgrey;
}
```

Adjust borders as required.

Comment: How would I get the 1p pixel border outlining the angle instead of a solid shape? As you can tell from the gradient on the image, the background is transparent, the borders are what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: That requires an additional pseudo element that is slightly larger. Note, you will also need to set different colors and margins. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DzeCv/ Frankly, if you need transparency, I'd go with SVG.

Comment: Yeah I didn't really do a good job of explaining the question. Thanks for your help though.